# "HTTP Status 404" and there is an extra "wrong path" in request path

Tags: spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

This is my practice Spring project. I can not redirect to the right page in SpringMVC Interceptor.

spring-mvc.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <description>Spring MVC Configuration</description>


    <context:property-placeholder ignore-unresolvable="true" location="classpath:myshop.properties"/>


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.huahua.my.shop" use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>


    <mvc:annotation-driven />


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="${web.view.prefix}"/>
        <property name="suffix" value="${web.view.suffix}"/>
    </bean>


    <mvc:resources mapping="/**/static/**" location="/static/" cache-period="31536000"/>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
            <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/login"/>
            <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/static/**"/>
            <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/loginOut"/>
            <bean class="com.huahua.my.shop.web.admin.web.intercepter.LoginIntercepter" />
        </mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/login"/>
            <bean class="com.huahua.my.shop.web.admin.web.intercepter.PermissionIntercepter" />
        </mvc:interceptor>
    </mvc:interceptors>
</beans>
```

this is `UserController` class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/user")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    TbUserService tbUserService ;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String userList(){
        return "user_list" ;
    }
}
```

this is my interceptor

```
public class LoginIntercepter implements HandlerInterceptor {

    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Object o ) throws Exception {

        TbUser tbUser =(TbUser) httpServletRequest.getSession().getAttribute(ConstantUtils.SESSION_USER);  //SESSION_USER = user
        System.out.println(httpServletRequest.getRequestURL());
        if (tbUser == null){
            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("login");
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Object o, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {}

    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Object o, Exception e) throws Exception {}
}
```

this is `LoginController`

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @Autowired
    private TbUserService tbuserService ;

    @RequestMapping(value = {"","login"},method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(){
        return "login" ;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "login",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@RequestParam(required = true) String email ,
                        @RequestParam(required = true ) String password ,
                        @RequestParam(required = false) String isRemember,
                        HttpServletRequest request,
                        Model model){
        TbUser user = tbuserService.loginRight(email, password);
        isRemember = isRemember == "on" ? "checked" : null ;
        if (user != null ){
            request.getSession().setAttribute(ConstantUtils.SESSION_USER,user);
            request.getSession().setAttribute("remember",isRemember);
            return "redirect:/main" ;
        }

        else {
            model.addAttribute("message","username or password is wrong");
            return "login" ;
        }

    }
```

1. when I log in and request `http://localhost:8080/user/list` , I successfully entered `user_list.jsp`.
2. after a time, this session is out of time，I refresh this page, 
   [the HTTP of refresh user_list page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZvC3.png)
   I hope it is redirected to `http://localhost:8080/login`,

   but I got this path `http://localhost:8080/user/login`
   [wrong with 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMi9P.png)
3. how can I solve this wrong?
4. why there is extra a '/user' in the path?
   and what are the relation between the `/user` in redirect path and the `@RequestMapping(value = "/user")` in UserController ?
5. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the API docs note for `HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect`:

> Sends a temporary redirect response to the client using the specified
>   redirect location URL and clears the buffer. The buffer will be
>   replaced with the data set by this method. Calling this method sets
>   the status code to SC_FOUND 302 (Found). This method can accept
>   relative URLs;the servlet container must convert the relative URL to
>   an absolute URL before sending the response to the client. **If the
>   location is relative without a leading '/' the container interprets it
>   as relative to the current request URI**. If the location is relative
>   with a leading '/' the container interprets it as relative to the
>   servlet container root.

So because you have specified a relative URL is resolved relative to the current request URl `/users/list`

So you need to change it to:

```
httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/login");
```